# Including dll to Visual Studio project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, nuget-package, .net-standard-2.0

I need to read a mat file in a Visual Studio project. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 32bit on Windows 10 64 bit.
I have installed a MatFileHandler library using NuGet Package Manager and got a MatFileHandler.dll file but I don't know how to use it. In program I've written `use MatFileHandler` but linker does not see this. Please don't judge me, I'm very new to Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MatFileHandler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MatFileHandler) library is not a native C++ dll. It's .NET assembly and it depends on [`.NETStandard 2.0`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-standard-2-0/).

You should create .NET application and add this NuGet package to it. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio) is the step-by-step instruction on how to create .NET Core application.